# Dropdown in which manually write also and convert the number automatically into comma separated

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I make the the dropdown in which pass the integer value but now I have to make the dropdown in which I write manually and the number which I write automatically comma separated but the value pass to the backend is without comma separated number.
My View:

```html
<select asp-for="Input.price" placeholder="Please Select price" style="height:50px; border-style:solid ;border-color: black;border-radius:5px; margin-left:20px;">
  <option value="" hidden>Select Price</option>
  <option value="500000">5,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="1000000">10,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="1500000">15,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="2000000">20,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="2500000">25,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="3000000">30,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="3500000">35,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="4000000">40,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="4500000">45,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="5000000">50,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="5500000">55,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="6000000">60,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="6500000">65,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="7000000">70,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="7500000">75,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="8000000">80,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="8500000">85,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="7000000">70,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="7500000">75,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="8000000">80,00,000 RS</option>
  <option value="8500000">85,00,000 Rs</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) in combination with a hidden field

Changing it on the backend is of course also an option if you have access. You still need to do proper input cleaning there.

Note the conversion needs the currency sign to be where it is expected. Here in front of the number in the data list

```js
const num2rs = val => val.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
});
document.getElementById("rsInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.value = num2rs(+this.value.replace(/\D/g,""))
  document.getElementById("Input.price").value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,"")
})
```

```html
<!-- make this type="hidden" and remove the br -->
<input type="text" name="Input.price" id="Input.price" /><br/>
<!-- Hidden field above-->

<input list="Input.price.list" id="rsInput" placeholder="Please Select price"> 
<datalist id="Input.price.list">
  <option value="₹5,00,000">
  <option value="₹10,00,000">
  <option value="₹15,00,000">
  <option value="₹20,00,000">
  <option value="₹25,00,000">
  <option value="₹30,00,000">
  <option value="₹35,00,000">
  <option value="₹40,00,000">
  <option value="₹45,00,000">
  <option value="₹50,00,000">
  <option value="₹55,00,000">
  <option value="₹60,00,000">
  <option value="₹65,00,000">
  <option value="₹70,00,000">
  <option value="₹75,00,000">
  <option value="₹80,00,000">
  <option value="₹85,00,000">
  <option value="₹70,00,000">
  <option value="₹75,00,000">
  <option value="₹80,00,000">
  <option value="₹85,00,000">
</datalist>
```

Comment: but it not separate the numeric value with comma automatically?

Comment: i just say that when i write numeric value it automatically separate the numbers into the form of thousands it display the comma separated value but pass the without comma separated value you done almost but when i write numeric value into the field it cannot automatically separate with comma

Comment: Ok, I understand. I could only do that with the ₹ in front

Comment: sign is not important

Comment: it works now with the sign

Comment: can we use it without sign

Comment: Probably. It is easier to use the toLocaleString